# TYPO3 userFunc give GET Parameter to php file

Tags: php, parameters, typo3, typoscript

I am including a php file via userFunc and want to give the get parameter "?session_start=1" and use this in the function.

TS:

```
includeLibs.voucher = fileadmin/php/shop_init.php
lib.phpscript = USER
lib.phpscript.userFunc = voucher->init
lib.phpscript.session_start_var = GP:session_start
```

php file

```
<?php
class voucher {
 public function init($content ="", $conf){

$session_start = $conf['session_start_var']?t3lib_div::_GP($conf['session_start_var']):false;



$lang_id = ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid == 0 ? "&lang=de" : "&lang=en");
 if($_GET["session_start"] == "" && $_GET["tx"] == "" && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari')){

  if($_GET["type"] == 1)
    die(header("Location:http://xx.pro/post?shop=1&s=1&referer=http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]$lang_id"));
  elseif($_GET["type"] == 2)
    die(header("Location:http://xx.pro/post?shop=2&s=1$lang_id"));
  elseif($_GET["type"] == 3)
    die(header("Location:http://xx.pro/post?shop=3&s=1$lang_id"));
  else
    die(header("Location:http://xx.pro/post?s=1$lang_id"));

}  

 return "<iframe id='frame-one' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'  style='".($_GET["type"] == "" ? "height:1640px;" : "height:1640px;")." width:100%;' src='http://xx.pro/post/index.php?view=".$_GET["view"]."&tx=".$_GET["tx"]."&st=".$_GET["st"]."&amt=".$_GET["amt"]."&type=".$_GET["type"]."$lang_id' ></iframe>";
 }
}
?>
```

when I echo $session_start the output = GP:session_start and not 1

thx in advance

Comment: So, it's you again. And you're still trying to bash php code into TYPO3 through some loopback hole, a prehistoric tech that should have long been removed. Stomping it in there with both feet regardless of all caching and any security measure TYPO gives you. This actual plain code is exploitable with a cross site scripting attacks. Just learn how to write an actual Extension, it isn't all that hard. What the hell are you doing there anyway. Catching all requests and redirecting them, some based on language? Dude. TYPO3 has multi language capabilities built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you assign the GP wrong, try it like this:

```
includeLibs.voucher = fileadmin/php/shop_init.php
lib.phpscript = USER
lib.phpscript.userFunc = voucher->init
lib.phpscript.userFunc.session_start_var = TEXT
lib.phpscript.userFunc.session_start_var.data = GP:session_start
```