# Send typoscript parameter to userFunc

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I'm trying to send a get parameter to a `userFunc` in order to identify a page, but it doesn't seem to work. This is what I have:

```
########## CATEGORY CONTENT ##########
lib.categoryContent = COA
lib.categoryContent {
    10 < styles.content.get
    10 {
        select {
            pidInList.cObject = USER
            pidInList.cObject {
                userFunc = Vendor\Provider\UserFunc\PageIdByAlias->getPageIdByAlias
                alias = TEXT
                alias.data = GP:category
            }
        }
    }

    wrap = <categoryContent><![CDATA[|]]></categoryContent>
}
```

And in PHP:

```
/**
 * Returns page ID by alias
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getPageIdByAlias($content, $conf)
{
    $pageId = $this->pageRepository->getPageIdByAlias($conf["alias"]);
    return $pageId;
}
```

I have also tried:

```
alias.cObject = TEXT
alias.cObject.data = GP:category
```

But still, I only get the string `GP:category` in PHP.
I'm using TYPO3 7.6.11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TYPO3 userFunc give GET Parameter to php file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276482/typo3-userfunc-give-get-parameter-to-php-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your TypoScript is correct. However, since the rendering is delegated to a user-function the nested TypoScript properties are not executed - this has to happen in your custom user-function. The instance of `ContentObjectRenderer` is automatically injected to your custom class as property `PageIdByAlias::$cObj`.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Provider\UserFunc;

class PageIdByAlias
{
  /**
   * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer
   */
  public $cObj;

  protected $pageRepository;

  /**
   * Returns page ID by alias
   *
   * @var string $content
   * @var array $configuration
   * @return int|string
   **/
  public function getPageIdByAlias($content, array $configuration = null)
  {
    $pageId = 0;
    // apply stdWrap() rendering for property 'alias'
    // 3rd argument defines a custom default value if property is not set
    $alias = $this->cObj->stdWrapValue('alias', $configuration, null);
    if ($alias !== null) {
      $pageId = $this->pageRepository->getPageIdByAlias($alias);
    }
    return $pageId;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May you can use $_GET in userFunc?

Comment: Yes, but since I will pass more parameters, I would prefer to pass them from TypoScript.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this in your user function

```
$pageId = $this->cObj->stdWrap($conf['page_id'], $conf['page_id.']);
```

after using this in typoscript

```
page_id.cObject = TEXT
page_id.cObject.data = GP:category
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the solution working for me.
Pass your argument with cObject from the html (from fluid or wherever you want).

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.categoryContent" >{category.uid}</f:cObject>
```

Or

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.categoryContent" data="{category.uid}" />
```

Typoscript :

```
# Set argument to the current.
lib.category = TEXT
lib.category{
    current = 1 
}

lib.categoryContent = USER
lib.categoryContent{

    10 < styles.content.get
    10 {
        select {
            pidInList.cObject = USER
            pidInList.cObject {
                userFunc = Vendor\Provider\UserFunc\PageIdByAlias->getPageIdByAlias

                # Pass category id as argument
                alias = TEXT
                alias.value < lib.category
            }
        }
    }

    wrap = <categoryContent><![CDATA[|]]></categoryContent>
}
```

Comment: The question was not about Fluid templates. Besides that, the `alias` section is not automatically interpreted - even if the Fluid ViewHelper is being used.